# Can you ID these storage bins?

Tags: organisation

I've seen snapshots of official LEGO Group design studios in books published by DK and the like. They use neat, removable drawer inserts for sorting elements, but I haven't found them available anywhere online.

Does anyone know if these specific bins/drawer units can be purchased anywhere? Are they unique to the LEGO Group, or perhaps produced internally for internal use only?

[image: Drawer image]

[image: Drawer image close-up]

Source of images: *LEGO DC Universe Super Heroes Visual Dictionary,* 2012, DK Publishing (New York)

Comment: No answer after a few days. Hmm. Perhaps that's not unusual, but I wonder if it will take some more research. if someone thinks it worthwhile to share my question outside this Bricks site, please comment. Do you think I could ask the LEGO Group directly? If so, where do you think I could begin? Perhaps the customer service department?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Liam Nilsen](https://twitter.com/nilsenmuseum/status/872450905454596096) from The LEGO Idea Studio, he believes the storage bins *may* have been produced in-house by LEGO and are not commercially available.

[image]

The [online portfolio for GXN](http://gxn.3xn.com/#/projects/by-year/249-lego-idea-studio) (the designers of the studio) mentions:

> Bespoke elements are accompanied by [Open Desk furniture](https://www.opendesk.cc/) pieces, all
>   fabricated by local makers and assembled on site.

I couldn't find the drawers on the Open Desk furniture site but it seems the parts containers are designed to fit snugly into the drawers.

Comment: Very interesting info. Another option for the little plastic trays could be Room Copenhagen, which makes all the official LEGO storage trays and bins. They are also located in Denmark. But if Liam said they are made by LEGO directly that makes sense too.